# Python argparse: both optional and positional value for an argument

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

Consider the following usage:

```
usage: do.py [-h] [-s | -m] filename
```

This is not the complete usage. But I effectively want is `filename` to be an actual value of file and not:

```
--filename FILENAME
```

But also, `filename` should be optional so I can read from the standard input. Think about the `cat` program on UNIX.

You simply say:

```
cat filename
```

OR

```
cat
```

EDIT: Right now, if I execute the program `do.py` without any command line options, I will get an `error: too few arguments`. Instead I would still want it to execute even if I don't give it a valid `filename`. How do I do that?

Comment: These are nice-looking, if a little light, specifications. What is the question? Please edit the body of your post to include your attempt at a solution, and folks will point you in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: Right now if I execute the program do.py without any command line options, I will get an error: too few arguments. Instead I would still want it to execute even I don't have a filename.

Comment: required=False doesn't work for positionals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update 2:** From the ArgParse documentation,

> One of the more common uses of nargs='?' is to allow optional input and output files:
>
> ```
> >>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
> >>> parser.add_argument('infile', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('r'),
> ...                     default=sys.stdin)
> >>> parser.add_argument('outfile', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('w'),
> ...                     default=sys.stdout)
> >>> parser.parse_args(['input.txt', 'output.txt'])
> Namespace(infile=<open file 'input.txt', mode 'r' at 0x...>,
>           outfile=<open file 'output.txt', mode 'w' at 0x...>)
> >>> parser.parse_args([])
> Namespace(infile=<open file '<stdin>', mode 'r' at 0x...>,
>           outfile=<open file '<stdout>', mode 'w' at 0x...>)
> ```

**Original answer:**

This is straightforward: just add a positional argument with a default value and a `nargs='*'`.  The default value will be used if there are zero arguments, otherwise the arguments on the command line will be used:

```
>>> p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> p.add_argument('filename', nargs='*', default=['-'])
>>> p.parse_args([])
Namespace(filename=['-'])
>>> p.parse_args(['abc'])
Namespace(filename=['abc'])
```

Typically, `-` is used to refer to standard input / standard output.

Then you do something like this:

```
def get_inputs(ns):
    """Iterate over input files."""
    for path in ns.filename:
        if path == '-':
            yield sys.stdin
        else:
            yield open(path, 'r')
```

**Update:** I assumed you wanted multiple filenames, since `cat` takes multiple filenames.  You can use `nargs='?'` if you want either zero or one filename.

Comment: That is correct sir. I actually used the nargs option seeing it in the documentation. What I don't want is the user to see this:

usage: do.py [-h] [-s | -m] [filename [filename ...]]

He should only really see that filename is optional and is only a single value is possible for that.

Comment: that would be `nargs='?'` for zero or one positional; see http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#nargs

Comment: @flippex17: I'm having a hard time believing you when you say you saw the `nargs` option in the documentation... because you would surely see `'?'` if you had been looking at the documentation...

Comment: Oh great. Thanks. That's fine Dietrich. I did see the documentation. I did try '*' but it didn't strike me to use '?' which is terribly unfortunate. Thank you.

Comment: Also, I was looking at 2.7.3. So really sorry about that. Thank you.